# tFPDF not outputting special characters

Tags: php, fpdf

> What I need

Special characters to work on FPDF, either working with hardcoded strings or results from a DB query

> What I'm using

As suggested in some questions here at SO, I'm using tFPDF to get special-characters to work.

> Problem

It works on the strings that are retrieved from an MySQL database but not on my hardcoded strings.

> Inputs Example

**DB string:**
[image]
**Hardcoded equivalent:**
`Operação`

> Outputs Example

[image]

As you can see, the filled cell is the hardcoded one, and the non-filled is the result from the DB.

> Code

For hardcode output of table header cell, i'm using the following code:

```
$pdf->Cell($wO,$h,'Operação',1,0,'C',true);
```

To output the DB result, I'm using a similar code:

```
$pdf->Cell($wO,$h,$oper,1,0,'C',$fill);
```

I already tried `utf8_encode` but it only gives me rectangles instead of the characters...

Comment: what font are you using?

Comment: I'm using DejaVu, which is the unifont one, as suggested [here](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using **Arial** font on the table headers and print the cell like this so that it assumes the special character:

```
$pdf->Cell($wO,$h,'Opera'.chr(231).chr(227).'o',1,0,'C',true);
```

Then, I put the special font named **DejaVu** again so that it places the special characters on the DB results.
Hope it helps anyone with the same problem, I followed [this example](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script4.php) and got the char number...